# Is there a way of generating a *.designer.cs file from a resx file from within the YAML pipeline in AzureDevOps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-devops, yaml

I want to move a .NET solution into AzureDevOps and have it build as part of a YAML pipeline:

The solution contains a .resx file that needs PublicResXFileCodeGenerator run on it to produce a *.Designer.cs file.
i.e. In a manual build of the solution in Visual Studio I right click on the file and select "run custom tool".

If I build this solution in AzureDevOps I currently get the error message:

##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'D:\a\1\s\solution1\Translations\Translations.Designer.cs' could not be found.

Question:
How could I achieve this using YAML statements in an AzureDevOps pipeline?

I was hoping there might be a way of somehow invoking the custom tool. [For example: if I search the web I can see msbuild mentioned in regards to custom tools - but not in an AzureDevOps setting.]

(If I run resgen on Translations\Translations.resx on my Dev PC I just get a Translations.resources file. There would need to be a step to take this and create a *.Designer.cs file so this looks a no-go.)

Comment: Why do you need to generate `.designer.cs` at build server? It should be generated in the design time. Then to add some satellite assemblies you just need the translation resx files, no .cs file is required. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025415/3110834).

Comment: Hi, Did you get a chance to try out below solution? How did it go?

Comment: We moved the generation of this file out of the build server, basically followed @RezaAghaei 's advice. -> So I'd like to select that comment as the answer... .. .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Resgen tool to generate the *.Designer.cs file. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/resgen-exe-resource-file-generator#performing-specific-resgenexe-tasks) for more information.

To generate .cs file from .resx file via Resgen in azure pipeline. You just need to add a script task to run the resgen command.

Resgen tool can be found in folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools` of the windows-2019/vs2017-win2016 cloud agent. See [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#net-framework).

See below example in powershell task.:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools"
   
    .\resgen.exe "$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\path\to\myresxfile.resx"  /str:cs
```

Comment: Isn't `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools` in the PATH on the build agents?

Comment: On Windows 10 with VS 2019 command prompt `resgen.exe "path\to\myresxfile.resx"  /str:cs` command is only generating .resources file for me not .cs