# How can I save the resource entries which I'm editing in a DataGridView to a Resx File?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a file resource.resx and I get data and put in datagridView but I would like change the parameters. bellow my cod

```
Dictionary<string, string> resourceMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string filename = @"C:/a/Res.resx";
ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(filename);
foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(d.Key.ToString(), d.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I´m new in C# I not know how make this change. What do I need to change in my code? I put all code in question

Comment: I believe the provided answer is pretty straightforward and you can easily make it working. Please try the solution, debug the code and if you encounter a problem, ask some specific question including the [MCVE], debug information, current behavior and expected behavior. You may also want to read [ASK].

Comment: Okay understand... My doubt is about comment:  "save it to a file." how can save in file?

Comment: Something like `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\myfile.resx", resX);` where `resX` is the content of the file.

Comment: Also as mentioned in the answer, you can take a look at [docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resxresourcewriter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#examples) as well. But I assume my example here is easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This post only covers writing in a ResX file. The ResX file will not be converted to a satellite assembly automatically. If you are interested in converting it to a satellite assembly, then take a look at: [Convert a Resources.Resx file to a satellite Assembly at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51027241/3110834).

There are several solutions to write in a ResX resource file. As an option, you can use a [ResXResourceWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resxresourcewriter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which accepts a stream or a filename and then you can add resource entries to the writer by calling [AddResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resxresourcewriter.addresource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method.

Assuming you have a model like this:

```
public  class MyResourceItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then I assume you display the items the DataGridView like this:

```
BindingList<MyResourceItem> model;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    model = new BindingList<MyResourceItem>();
    // You may have some logic to load resources into the model
    // Then show it in DataGridView
    dataGridView1.DataSource = model;
}
```

Then you can have a method to get the ResX string content like this:

```
public string ToResXFileContent(List<MyResourceItem> model)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(sw))
        foreach (var item in model)
            writer.AddResource(item.Name, item.Value);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then you can get the ResX representation of your model:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var resX = ToResXFileContent(model.ToList());
    //And save it to a file.
}
```

As I mentioned above, you can also [save the content directly to a ResX file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resxresourcewriter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#examples), like the Docs example.